# Inheritance and Overriding Methods/Properties

Tags: c#, inheritance

If I have two classes, one which inherits from the other and I use the same method/property name in both, how can I make that method call the subclass regardless of whether the current object has been cast back to it's base class.

For example (extraneous parts omitted):

```
public class MyBase {
    public int GetNumber() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class MyDerived : MyBase {
    public new int GetNumber() {
        return 20;
    }
}

MyDervied someVar = new MyDerived();
int derivedVar = someVar.GetNumber(); // 20

MyBase baseVar = (MyBase)someVar;
int baseVar = baseVar.GetNumber(); // 1
```

My instinct would be to use override instead of new for the derived class, but I get a "no member found to override".

Comment: Perhaps I should have posted a specific example. I'm trying to use the same base class in WPF and ASP.NET. WPF makes use of INotifyPropertyChanged, so I'm actually trying to change the return type of the base from List<string> to ObservableCollection<string>. Initially I tried using an IList in the base class without luck.

Comment: Rather than change the type returned by the method, you may just want to transform the data within the WPF code that consumes it. If you keep the return type as List<string>, you can just pass the returned value into the constructor of ObservableCollection. You may want to ask a new question with more details to get more specific advice.

Comment: Thanks. The reason I need the ObservableCollection is due to bindings on controls, which need the change notification.

Answer (score 7):

Your base method needs to be marked `virtual` before you can `override`.

```
public class MyBase {
    public virtual int GetNumber() {
        return 1;
    }
}

public class MyDerived : MyBase {
    public override int GetNumber() {
        return 20;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dahlbyk is right. `new` is useful if you want to derive a class and add a new member, but *coincidentally* the class already has a member with the same name. It's for adding a new member, not for changing the behaviour of an existing one.

```
class A
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("A.Foo()");
    }
}

class B : A
{
    public new void Foo()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("B.Foo()");
    }
}

...

A x = new A();
x.Foo(); // prints "A.Foo()"

B y = new B();   
y.Foo(); // prints "B.Foo()"

A z = y;
z.Foo(); // prints "A.Foo()", not "B.Foo()"!
```

Note the difference in behaviour when compared to an overridden method, which would print `"B.Foo()"` in the latter case.

Comment: Thanks. Perhaps I should have posted a specific example. I'm trying to use the same class in WPF and ASP.NET. WPF makes use of INotifyPropertyChanged, so I'm actually trying to change the return type of the base from List<string> to ObservableCollection<string>.